# Regex: How to match a string that is not only numbers

Tags: regex

Is it possible to write a regular expression that matches all strings that does not *only* contain numbers? If we have these strings:

- **abc**
- **a4c**
- **4bc**
- **ab4**
- 123

It should match the four first, but not the last one. I have tried fiddling around in RegexBuddy with lookaheads and stuff, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
(?!^\d+$)^.+$
```

This says lookahead for lines that do not contain all digits and match the entire line.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up with :)

Comment: So...basically you came up with a complicated expression for /\D/.

Comment: Well no \D is different than mine because it only matches non digits. Mine returns matches that include the entire string when a match is made while just \D could be multiple matches per line. My regex returns 4 matches while \D returns 17 (for each non-digit).

Comment: @Mike Cheel I see. If that's what Svish was looking for, it definitely wasn't clear from his question. I see how that could be advantageous though.

Comment: @Daniel, how was that not clear from my question? I even had 5 examples where I marked the strings I wanted matched...

Comment: I think I finally understand the confusion. The answer I gave assumed that you were checking each of these strings separately. Indeed before answering your question, I wrote a script printed each string that matched the regular expression, which gave the output you requested. But it appears you wanted a regex that would pull out each of these substrings individually from a larger string. Based on the responses, I was not the only one that thought this.

Comment: the simplicity is so nice

Comment: what if you want to capture only a specific part of each line (the part which contains the strings given as example in the original question), and also limit the length of the captured group (like in the example, the length was always 3)?

Answer (score 15):

Unless I am missing something, I think the most concise regex is...

```
/\D/
```

...or in other words, is there a not-digit in the string?

Comment: this will fail if there is a digit in the string as far as I can see

Comment: @Svish: your statement makes no sense.

Comment: I did. And this does not match a string that does not contain only numbers. It matches a single letter that is not a digit. If I put that between a ^ and a $ for matching a string, it matches only the first of my test strings.

Comment: Well, the behaviour of the two is slightly different, you can see in my ruby code here:

`codes = ['abc', 'a4c', '4bc', 'ab4', '123']`
`codes.map { |code| code.match(/\D/) }`
`=> [#<MatchData "a">, #<MatchData "a">, #<MatchData "b">, #<MatchData "a">, nil]`
`codes.map { |code| code.match(/(?!^\d+$)^.+$/) }`
`=> [#<MatchData "abc">, #<MatchData "a4c">, #<MatchData "4bc">, #<MatchData "ab4">, nil]`

Comment: The match data for the `/\D/` returns for the first letter, while the match for the mote complex one returns the whole code from the example. All in all, they appear to be both equally usable unless, for some reason, you need perform operations on the matched data.

Answer (score 10):

jjnguy had it correct (if slightly redundant) in an [earlier revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3831083/revisions).

```
.*?[^0-9].*
```

[@Chad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831051/regex-how-to-match-a-string-that-is-not-only-numbers/3831482#3831482), your regex,

```
\b.*[a-zA-Z]+.*\b
```

should probably allow for non letters (eg, punctuation) even though Svish's examples didn't include one. Svish's primary requirement was: not all be digits.

```
\b.*[^0-9]+.*\b
```

Then, you don't need the + in there since all you need is to guarantee 1 non-digit is in there (more might be in there as covered by the .* on the ends).

```
\b.*[^0-9].*\b
```

Next, you can do away with the \b on either end since these are unnecessary constraints (invoking reference to alphanum and _).

```
.*[^0-9].*
```

Finally, note that this last regex shows that the problem can be solved with just the basics, those basics which have existed for decades (eg, no need for the look-ahead feature). In English, the question was logically equivalent to simply asking that 1 counter-example character be found within a string.

We can test this regex in a browser by copying the following into the location bar, replacing the string "6576576i7567" with whatever you want to test.

```
javascript:alert(new String("6576576i7567").match(".*[^0-9].*"));
```

Answer (score 8):

```
/^\d*[a-z][a-z\d]*$/
```

Or, case insensitive version:

```
/^\d*[a-z][a-z\d]*$/i
```

May be a digit at the beginning, then at least one letter, then letters or digits

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
/^.*\D+.*$/
```

It returns true if there is any simbol, that is not a number. Works fine with all languages.

Answer (score 3):

Since you said "**match**", not just validate, the following regex will match correctly

```
\b.*[a-zA-Z]+.*\b
```

Passing Tests:

```
abc
a4c
4bc
ab4
1b1
11b
b11
```

Failing Tests:

```
123
```

Comment: @Jin, depends, `[a-zA-Z]` is not the same as `\D`. `\D` is "not a digit".  So if they're literally not wanting 0-9 and are ok with punctuation, then yes, `\D` would be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to match worlds that have at least one letter but they are formed by numbers and letters (or just letters), this is what I have used:

```
(\d*[a-zA-Z]+\d*)+
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to restrict valid characters so that string can be made from a limited set of characters, try this:

```
(?!^\d+$)^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,}$
```

or

```
(?!^\d+$)^[\w-]{3,}$
```

/\w+/: 
Matches any letter, number or underscore. any word character

Comment: Look ahead works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
.*[^0-9]{1,}.*
```

Works fine for us.

We want to use the used answer, but it's not working within YANG model.

And the one I provided here is easy to understand and it's clear:
start and end could be any chars, but, but there must be at least one NON NUMERICAL characters, which is greatest.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `/^[0-9]*$/gm` in my JavaScript code to see if string is only numbers. If yes then it should fail otherwise it will return the string.

Below is working code snippet with test cases:

```js
function isValidURL(string) {
  var res = string.match(/^[0-9]*$/gm);
  if (res == null)
    return string;
  else
    return "fail";
};

var testCase1 = "abc";
console.log(isValidURL(testCase1)); // abc

var testCase2 = "a4c";
console.log(isValidURL(testCase2)); // a4c

var testCase3 = "4bc";
console.log(isValidURL(testCase3)); // 4bc

var testCase4 = "ab4";
console.log(isValidURL(testCase4)); // ab4

var testCase5 = "123"; // fail here
console.log(isValidURL(testCase5));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar in MySQL and the following whilst over simplified seems to have worked for me:

where fieldname regexp `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`
and fieldname NOT REGEXP `^[0-9]+$`

This shows all fields that are alphabetical and alphanumeric but any fields that are just numeric are hidden. This seems to work.

example:

name1 - Displayed
name  - Displayed
name2 - Displayed
name3 - Displayed
name4 - Displayed
n4ame - Displayed
324234234 - Not Displayed

Comment: Not really sure why someone has edited this but not really changed anything then marked it down when the solution works perfectly. (I implemented it myself)