# How to set strings in a pandas dataframe to another value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains strings and numbers:

```
> print(f1)

    0    1
0  Hi    0
1   5  Bye
2   6    9
3   7   10

> print(type(f1))

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

I want to set all the string values to 0. That is, I wish to get the following output:

```
    0    1
0   0    0
1   5    0
2   6    9
3   7   10
```

My attempt involved trying both of these statements,

```
print(f1.select_dtypes(include=[numpy.number]))
print(f1.select_dtypes(exclude=[object]))
```

but both times I get an empty dataframe as output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

What else could I try to get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible ways:

If all values are strings use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for replace strings to `NaN`s and then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
print (df.applymap(type))
               0              1
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
2  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
3  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>


df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   0   1
0  0   0
1  5   0
2  6   9
3  7  10
```

Or if mixed types use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
print (df.applymap(type))
               0              1
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
1  <class 'int'>  <class 'str'>
2  <class 'int'>  <class 'int'>
3  <class 'int'>  <class 'int'>


df = df.mask(df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)), 0)
print (df)
   0   1
0  0   0
1  5   0
2  6   9
3  7  10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regex, from here: [Regex: How to match a string that is not only numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831051/regex-how-to-match-a-string-that-is-not-only-numbers). This won't work for floats though (e.g. 3.14):

```
df = df.replace(r'(?!^\d+$)^.+$', 0, regex=True).astype(int)
```