# check expression with minimum 3 character and not start with Space

Tags: expression

My code is currently using the following Regular expression which matches on numbers:

```
/^([^0-9]*)$/
```

it's working fine when I'm putting Character and Special Character like

```
hello
merry#
mom&dad
```

but when I'm trying with a number it's not giving me a proper result

```
hello 22
mom&dad44
mm88$
```

I want output like this

```
1234       - Not Allow
   mnb5    - Not Allow
123Hello   - Not Allow
Hello123   - Allow
hello      - Allow
Hello%     - Allow
Hello%123  - Allow
hello 123  - Allow
Hello #    - Allow
```

I want Minimum 3 characters and it does not start with Space and number

Comment: The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3831442/3832970). If you need to adjust it for the 3 char minimum, replace `+` with `{3,}`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this regex without anchors:

```
/\D/
```

This will match a non-digit i.e. `\D` anywhere in a line.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BVX8yB/1)

Comment: I also want a minimum 3 Character with a number like 12h, 5ok, kkk, etc

Comment: @MinhajPatel: Can you update your question with these examples so that I understand it better.