# How do I execlude only numbers in this regular expression?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to match words that look like this

```
:test:
:soda_stream:
:test3:
```

and so on. What I have now is `\:\S+\:` and it works for everything except I also have parts in the text that have only numbers, like `:23:`. These I want to exclude, but are unsuccessful in doing that. I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831051/regex-how-to-match-a-string-that-is-not-only-numbers) StackOverflow page, but it does not work.

Do anyone know how to do it? It probably is just some addition that exclude if there is only numbers inside the `:`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account current examples, you may use

```
:(?!\d+:)[^\s:]+:
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T2s51w/1)

**Details**

- `:` - a colon
- `(?!\d+:)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are one or more digits and then `:` immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^\s:]+` - 1 or more characters other than whitespace and a colon
- `:` - a colon

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could match at least a single char that is not a digit or a whitespace char in between the colons:

```
:[^:\s]*[^:\s\d][^:\s]*:
```

- `:` Match literally
- `[^:\s]*` Match 0+ times any char except : or a whitespace char
- `[^:\s\d]` Match any char except : or a whitespace char or a digit
- `[^:\s]*` Match 0+ times any char except : or a whitespace char
- `:` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q0bxdR/1)