# Can a YouTube video be comprised of only numbers, if so how to match a string that is not only numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

EDIT: I recently found out(with help from some kind Stack Overflow users) that there are valid YouTube videos that *are* only letters.

<s>Same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831051/regex-how-to-match-a-string-that-is-not-only-numbers/3831442) **but with the addition of checking letters into the equation**.</s>

I was wondering if it is possible for the video ids for YouTube videos to be comprised of just numbers like this:
`12345678901`.
I'm writing an expression to validate a string that is a YouTube video id. Here is a simplified version of the expression in action(source [here](https://github.com/UnrealApex/yt-player) for further debugging):

```js
const foo = /((http?(?:s)?:?\/\/)?(www\.)?)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?&v=))((?:\w|-){11})((?:\&|\?)\S*)?|(?:^(\w|-){11}$)|(?:\w|-){11}$/;

let bar = "dQw4w9WgXcQ"

// logs true
console.log("is valid: " + foo.test(bar));
```

Is it possible to write a regular expression that matches a string that does not only contain numbers <s>or letters</s>?

#### Criteria

These should work:

- abcdefghijk
- ecK3EnyGD8o
- 1s3get2-3ds
- 4bc2qfs2wrf
- 28yq389gfwg
- 3oyh8pw489p

But these shouldn't:

- <s>abcdefghijk</s>
- 12345678910? (unknown at the moment if YouTube supports video ids that are only numbers)
- 18974107892351240891751928347819234
- Stack Overflow
- kjsad;kflj;klasdfkjalk;sdfjlkas
- !*&$@#)&&*()%&*(#@$&(

Comment: Why can't a YouTube ID contain only numbers?  Admittedly there probably aren't many of these, but they might exist.

Comment: @Tim With a quick search, I found `aoIfitMrAss` and `PISsBoyFztM`. They're IDs of two actual YT videos. (sorry, a bit inappropriate, I know but I only found them because people like to share "funny" stuff)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think video ids can contain only numbers or letters. I'll check YouTube's documentation on that.

Comment: They definitely _can_ be all letters, per the comment by @41686d6564 above.  Not sure on all numbers, but I don't see why not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen possibly.

Comment: [Try](https://regex101.com/r/hCapiw/1) - `\b([-a-zA-Z]+\d+|\d+[-a-zA-Z]+)[-a-zA-Z0-9]*\b`

Comment: Works, but I've realized and as @41686d6564 mentioned, some letter-only ids are valid.

Comment: [Updated](https://regex101.com/r/hCapiw/2). Does this satisfy your needs?

Comment: Yep, thanks! All that needs to be done is confirming that YouTube video ids can't be just integers.

Comment: The thread you linked to contains the [exact solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3831078/3832970). Please check if it is solving the issue and let know.

Comment: I'm still unsure if video ids can be just numbers, if isn't possible, then you are correct.

Comment: @UnrealApex _"unknown at the moment if YouTube supports video ids that are only numbers"_ The question is: why do you care? Don't enforce a restriction unless the official documentation explicitly states that certain combinations are not valid (which, AFAICT, is not the case). You might find [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/54448/273649) useful.

Comment: I do see your point. I care because I feel that notifying the user before they play a invalid url seems to be better than them playing it and getting a "video not found" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
^[\d_-]*[a-zA-Z][-\w]*$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/vnHkCa/2).

**EXPLANATION**

| Part of Expression | What it Does |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `[\d_-]*` | any character of: digits (`0-9`), `_`, `-` (0 or more times(matching the most amount possible)) |
| `[a-zA-Z]` | any character of: `a-z`, `A-Z` |
| `[-\w]*` | any character of: `-` word characters (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`) (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `$` | before an optional \n, and the end of the string |

**JavaScript code**:

```js
const oks = [
  'abcdefghijk',
  'ecK3EnyGD8o',
  '1s3get2-3ds',
  '4bc2qfs2wrf',
  '28yq389gfwg',
  '3oyh8pw489p'
];

const nonoks = [
  '12345678910',
  '18974107892351240891751928347819234',
  'Stack Overflow',
  'kjsad;kflj;klasdfkjalk;sdfjlkas',
  '!&$@#)&&()%&*(#@$&('
];

const regex = /^[\d_-]*[a-zA-Z][-\w]*$/;

for (const i of oks)
  console.log(i, regex.test(i))

for (const i of nonoks)
  console.log(i, regex.test(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Used a negative lookahead to check if its not all numbers,
then followed by a check if its all word characters and a dash only pattern.

```
/^(?!\d+$)[\w\-]+$/
```

```js
let valids = [
  'abcdefghijk',
  'ecK3EnyGD8o',
  '1s3get2-3ds',
  '4bc2qfs2wrf',
  '28yq389gfwg',
  '3oyh8pw489p'
];

let invalids = [
  '12345678910',
  '18974107892351240891751928347819234',
  'Stack Overflow',
  'kjsad;kflj;klasdfkjalk;sdfjlkas',
  '!&$@#)&&()%&*(#@$&('
];

let pattern = /^(?!\d+$)[\w\-]+$/;

for (var i = 0; i < valids.length; i++)
  console.log(valids[i], pattern.test(valids[i]))

for (var i = 0; i < invalids.length; i++)
  console.log(invalids[i], pattern.test(invalids[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```js
const re = /[\w]*(\p{L}\d|\d\p{L})[\w]*/u;

console.log("abcdefghijk".match( re ) || "Failed");
console.log("ecK3EnyGD8o".match( re ) || "Failed");
console.log("1s3get2-3ds".match( re ) || "Failed");
console.log("4bc2qfs2wrf".match( re ) || "Failed");
console.log("28yq389gfwg".match( re ) || "Failed");
console.log("3oyh8pw489p".match( re ) || "Failed");
console.log("12345678910".match( re ) || "Failed");
console.log("18974107892351240891751928347819234".match( re ) || "Failed");
console.log("Stack Overflow".match( re ) || "Failed");
console.log("kjsad;kflj;klasdfkjalk;sdfjlkas".match( re ) || "Failed");
console.log("!&$@#)&&()%&*(#@$&(".match( re ) || "Failed");
```

You meant for "abcdefghijk" to be a fail case right?  It only contains letters.

"1s3get2-3ds" will fail as it contains a hyphen.  If you want to consider valid symbols just add them to the "[\w]", like so for hyphen: [-\w]

Comment: It's been confirmed by @41686d6564 that are a few valid letter only video ids see their comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Used regex:

```
/^([a-zA-Z-]+|[a-zA-Z0-9-]*?([a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9-]*?)$/
```

Regex in testbench and context:

```
const validFormat = ["abcdefghijk", "ecK3EnyGD8o", "1s3get2-3ds"
, "4bc2qfs2wrf" , "28yq389gfwg", "3oyh8pw489p"];

const invalidInput = ["12345678910", "18974107892351240891751928347819234"
, "Stack Overflow", "kjsad;kflj;klasdfkjalk;sdfjlkas", "!&$@#)&&()%&*(#@$&("];

const validAndInvalidInput = validFormat.concat(invalidInput);

const regex = /^([a-zA-Z-]+|[a-zA-Z0-9-]*?([a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9-]*?)$/;
for(const input of validAndInvalidInput) {
    console.log(input, ' -> ', regex.test(input));
}
```

Console output:

```
abcdefghijk  ->  true
ecK3EnyGD8o  ->  true
1s3get2-3ds  ->  true
4bc2qfs2wrf  ->  true
28yq389gfwg  ->  true
3oyh8pw489p  ->  true
12345678910  ->  false
18974107892351240891751928347819234  ->  false
Stack Overflow  ->  false
kjsad;kflj;klasdfkjalk;sdfjlkas  ->  false
!&$@#)&&()%&*(#@$&(  ->  false
```