# How to match string if it doesn't contain only numbers after slash?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am redirecting certain urls with path to get variables like the following:

```
localhost2/post/myTitle => localhost2/post.php?title=myTitle
localhost2/post/123 => localhost2/post.php?id=123
```

So In my htaccess file, I use

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^post/(\d+) post.php?id=$1
    RewriteRule ^post/(.*) post.php?title=$1
 </IfModule>
```

This works no problem. But I want to learn how to write negative of `^post/(\d+)`, that is `^post/(NEGATE-ONLY-NUMBERS)`. In other words I want a regex that matches the whole input sting if there is not only numbers after `post/`. So `post/abc`, `post/a23`, `post/ab3`, `post/12c` and `post/a2c` should all pass but not `post/123`. I refered to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3831051/3429430), which suggest using:

```
(?!^\d+$)^.+$
```

I can't use `^post/(?!^\d+$)^.+$`, because there can be only one `^` and one `$`. I  don't know what regex anchor specifies first position in a substring. My best guess is

```
post\/(?!\d++).*
```

I think `(?!\d++)`, with the `++` would eat all characters followig and check if all are digits. But this fails at `post/1ab`.

Another guess is:

```
post\/(?![\d,\/]+$).*
```

The works the best but it allows: `post/3455/X`.
Secondly, eventually I need to convert `localhost2/post/myTitle/123 => localhost2/post.php?title=myTitle&repeat=123` as well. I ave come up with the following:

```
^post/(?!\d+($|/))(.+?($|/))(\d+$)?
```

Note: `+?` to use lazy quantifier, otherwise multiple slashes will be matched by `.`

and

```
^post/(?!\d+($|/))([^/\n\r]+($|/))(\d+$)?
```

Here I use `[^/\n\r]` instead of `.+?`

Answer (score 3):

Patterns inside zero-width assertions like `(?!\d++)`  are non-consuming, they do not "eat" chars, they only check the context while keeping the regex index at the same location as before matching the zero-width assertion pattern.

You can use any of the following:

```
^post/(?!\d+(?:/|$)).*
^post/(?!\d+(?=/|$)).*
^post/(?!\d+(?![^/])).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/McRuJs/1). *Details*:

- `^post/` - start of input, `post/` literal string
- `(?!\d+(?=/|$))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are one or more digits followed with `/` or end of string
- `.*` - the rest of the input.

Comment: Your last alternative `^post/(?!\d+(?![^/])).*` matches `post/123` as well. I don't understand how can we use `^` for the second time in `[^/]`. Can you explain on that as well please.

Comment: Is `^post/(?!\d+/|$).*` a valid solution as well? I don't think we need a look ahead at all. `foobar` and `foo(?:bar)` act the same.

Comment: @user31782 `^post/(?!\d+(?![^/])).*` [does NOT match](https://regex101.com/r/McRuJs/2) `post/123`. Please only test the solutions in the target environment if you do not understand how a regex works in the testing environment. As I said, all solutions work for you.  `^post/(?!\d+/|$).*` WON'T work because you did not group `/` and `$`. `(?![^/])` = `(?=/|$)`, i.e. it matches either the end of string or a location that is immediately followed with a `/` char.

Comment: It was an issueof `newline`. Your last option matches if `post/123\n`, https://regex101.com/r/CRjNAw/1  which can be obviously remedied with `[^/\n\r]`. What I meant to ask with `^post/(?!\d+(/|$)).*` is aren't the subexpressions `(?=/|$)` and `(/|$)` equivalent for my case? Because the parent group is negated.

Comment: @user31782 The newline issue is *not a real issue* since it is just testing a multiline string in the online tester, which does not occur in the real environment, and you can use all three. `(?!\d+(/|$))` is a zero-width assertion, and it makes no difference if you use a group or a lookaround inside this zero-width assertion: the regex index will remain where it was before trying the ZWA pattern. There might be a difference if you use a capturing or non-capturing group, it is best practice to use non-capturing groups when you needn't access the capture (as is the case here).

Answer (score 2):

Do not over complicate things when you can keep things simple by keeping 3 separate rewrite rules and since your query parameters are named differently you will need 3 separate rewrite rules anyway.

Consider:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^post/(\d+) post.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/(\d+) post.php?title=$1&repeat=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*) post.php?title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Take note of `Options -MultiViews`. If this is not enabled in Apache config you must have it here otherwise it will keep all `$_GET` parameters empty in your php file.

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.

Comment: I need to include special characters in `title` as well. `[\w-]+` won't allow `Hello%20world`.

Comment: ok check my updated answer now

Comment: Things seem to work well without the flags as well. I can still use both `localhost2/PosT` and `localhost2/post`. Especially the QSA flag is redundant as well. Why is that?

Comment: `QSA` is not redundant. If your original URL is `localhost2/Post?foo=bar` then without `QSA` original query string i.e. `foo=bar` will be lost in your `post.php`

Comment: With your options being applied in my htaccess, `http://localhost2/post.php?id=3185` works perfect even if I don't use `QSA`. But, pages like `http://localhost2/post/Vijayalakshmi%20Singh/whatever` don't. With my code the later is equivalent to `http://localhost2/post.php?title=Vijayalakshmi%20Singh`

Comment: That's not the behavior I get on my local apache. I get `$_GET['title'] = "Vijayalakshmi Singh/whatever"` when I enter URL as: `http://localhost2/post/Vijayalakshmi%20Singh/whatever`

Comment: Now the links are working same as with my relatively complex regex. I still don't see any need for the flags. Everything work same without any flags.

Comment: No it does not. If `QSA` flag is missing then `$_GET` string will not carry original query string. e.g. If URI is `http://localhost2/post.php?id=3185` then printing `print_r($_GET);` will not show `id=3185`

Comment: Is there some global htaccess rule that does the same thig as `QSA`? In my apache localhost `print_r($_GET)` works perect without the `QSA` flag. I have the whole code on github if you want.

Comment: I am not aware of any global `QSA` setting. I have tested it on Apache `2.4.49` and without `QSA` original query string gets lost.

Comment: I have the whole code here: https://github.com/AnupamKhosla/crimeWiki  I will soon update that with your code and give link to the actual website that successfully pass `post.php?id=3185` without any flags.